# Как регуляркой удалить куски в тексте?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, в которой текст:

```html
random text 1***trash2***y6f dhy 1 month ago 14 minutes, 29 seconds 3,620 name***trash3***random text 1","random text 2***trash2***pot 5aq 3 months ago 9 minutes, 9 seconds 226,629 name***trash3***random text 2","random text 3***trash2***uan 4fp 5 months ago 26 minutes 506,950 name***trash3***random text 3"
```

Хочу удалить то, что выделил желтым и синим .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос/проблема:**
Я написал регулярку для удаления того что желтое: `***trash3***+([\s\S]+)"+`
Но она убирает все данные с первого до последнего совпадения найденного в строке..... по-сути оставляя только начало и конец от всей строки. А нужно чтоб удаляло каждый найденный кусок.

**Если не понятно, то далее я поясню подробнее:**

Желтое - это что между **name** и кавычкой  **"**

**Как я это хочу реализовать:**

В тексте, с помощью JS ищу регуляркой эти куски :

```html
***trash3***random text 1
***trash3***random text 2
***trash3***random text 3
```

и заменяю на "пустоту".

то есть удаляем `***trash3***` и сразу идущий после него любой рандомный текст до замыкающей кавычки (кавычку не удаляем).

**random text 1** - это какое-то рандомное предложение состоящее из нескольких слов.
Обратите внимание, что этот же самый рандомный текст стоит до `***trash2***` , но его мы не удаляем.

Tак-же хочу удалить такой рандомный текст :

```html
y6f dhy
pot 5aq
uan 4fp
```

Который идёт между `***trash2***` и `цифрой пробел и временным названием`. Типа `2 year`, `27 years`, `1 day`, `6 days`... и так далее.

А синим выделено - это то что между `***trash2***` и любое из этих значений:

```html
{цифра} minutes
{цифра} minute
{цифра} day
{цифра} days
{цифра} weeks
{цифра} week
{цифра} hours
{цифра} hour
{цифра} years
{цифра} year
{цифра} months
{цифра} month
```

Но скорее всего это уже следующей регуляркой, т.к в моём случае "чистку" можно разбить "на 2 раза....2 иттерации".

Comment: не понятно до какого символа вы ищете случайный текст. Если нет разделителя - то ве что после tash*** попадает под условие

Comment: до закрывающей кавычки .вот на скрине выделил её https://prnt.sc/1h650mv

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, можно так:

```js
const str = 'random text 1***trash2***y6f dhy 1 month ago 14 minutes, 29 seconds 3,620 name***trash3***random text 1","random text 2***trash2***pot 5aq 3 months ago 9 minutes, 9 seconds 226,629 name***trash3***random text 2","random text 3***trash2***uan 4fp 5 months ago 26 minutes 506,950 name***trash3***random text 3"';

const result = str
  .replace(/\*\*\*trash3\*\*\*[^"]+/g, '')
  .replace(/(?<=\*\*\*trash2\*\*\*)\w{3} \w{3}/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

Если нет поддержки заглядывания назад (lookbehind assertions):

```js
const str = 'random text 1***trash2***y6f dhy 1 month ago 14 minutes, 29 seconds 3,620 name***trash3***random text 1","random text 2***trash2***pot 5aq 3 months ago 9 minutes, 9 seconds 226,629 name***trash3***random text 2","random text 3***trash2***uan 4fp 5 months ago 26 minutes 506,950 name***trash3***random text 3"';

const result = str
  .replace(/\*\*\*trash3\*\*\*[^"]+/g, '')
  .replace(/\*\*\*trash2\*\*\*\w{3} \w{3}/g, '***trash2***');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Кстати, поставил переменную [[KOD_VSEY_STRANIZY]] в которой содержится строка текста для обработки. 

Поставил в таком виде:
const str = '[[KOD_VSEY_STRANIZY]]';


Но получаю в моём JS-обработчике "Browser Automation Studio"
Синтаксическую ошибку: https://prnt.sc/1h7ttoh

Comment: @Birykov Тогда скорее всего JS-движок вашего инструмента не поддерживает последних возможностей JS-регулярок.

Comment: @Birykov Добавил вариант без заглядывания назад. Хотя я не знаком с вашим инструментом и даже не понимаю, как в такой код интерполируется переменная со строкой, так что, возможно, со всеми проблемами не смогу помочь. Лучше вам в вопросе уточнить детали, при помощи чего вы обрабатываете текст.

Comment: в инструменте нет функции "console.log()"

Пробовал вот так


var str = '[[KOD_VSEY_STRANIZY]]';
log(str) //VAR_KOD_VSEY_STRANIZY
var result = str
  .replace(/\*\*\*trash3\*\*\*[^"]+/g, '')
  .replace(/(?<=\*\*\*trash2\*\*\*)\w{3} \w{3}/g, '');

log(result);


Но выдаёт ошибку: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (? во время выполнения действия

Comment: Я добавил в ответ второй вариант, пробуйте его)